# How to remove wire from insert connector in recessed light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

I want to remove a wire from this connector inside a can light junction box. I tried pulling it but it doesn't come out. Am I missing something here?

Take a look at picture of similar can. I know that in this picture the wire is integral to the fixture. I want to remove incoming wire from another similar can in celling.

[image]

Comment: Well, a connector wouldn't be much of a connector if simply pulling a wire made it come apart. :P

Answer (score 4):

If you were to detach the connector from the group retainer by releasing the tabs you might find a wire release tab or slot on the connector. Otherwise...

- Try twisting the wire as you pull. Sometimes they'll sort of screw out with a bit of effort. Remove the damaged portion of the wire and re-strip before using it elsewhere.
- Cut the wire and re-strip it. Leave a stub on the connector to which you could reconnect later, or which you can cap or tape to insulate the exposed wire. (You could also just loop it back into the same connector to secure and insulate it.)